# Object to array stack null value at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm actually working on a vue apexchart stat module and I have to handle null value,

So I have to count the number of event in a day and I have three type of event, a, b and c which can happen same or different day, so I end up with three objects:

```js
const ObjectA = [
{'20/10/21': 3},
{'25/10/21': 1}
],

const ObjectB = [
{'25/10/21': 4}
]
```

So I this case I want to have two arrays, which have to be that way:

```js
const ArrayA = [3,1]
const ArrayB = [null, 4]
```

So first of all I fill up the void between the two object this way to end up with these two:

```js
const ObjectA = [
{'20/10/21': 3},
{'25/10/21': 1}
],

const ObjectB = [
{'20/10/21': null},
{'25/10/21': 4}
]
```

But when I try to convert these objects to an array I always end up with the null value stacking at the end of my Array such as

```js
const ArrayA = [3,1]
const ArrayB = [4, null]
```

And whatever the method I'm using, `Object.values(ObjectX)`, a forEach loop with `Object.entries(ObjectX)` etc... I always have an array that does not fit my expectations.

So in a first time I'm wondering why the null values are always ended up at the end of my arrays and secondly I'm asking for an answer to see where I'm missing my point.

There is a preview to the actual code I'm using:

```js
 const momentStartDate = moment(paramStartDate)
 const momentEndDate = moment(paramEndDate)

 if (moment(created).isBetween(momentStartDate, momentEndDate, 'days', '[]')) {
   if (!newLabels.includes(createdDate)) {
     newLabels.push(createdDate)
   }
   if (!open[createdDate]) {
     open[createdDate] = 0
   }
    open[createdDate]++
 } else if ...

newLabels.forEach((item) => {
 if (open[item] === undefined) {
  open[item] = null
 }
})

[...]

const openTemp = []

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(open).length; i++) {
  openTemp.push(Object.values(open)[i])
}

Object.keys(closed).forEach((item) => {
  if (closed[item] === null) {
    openTemp.push(null)
  } else {
    openTemp.push(closed[item])
   }
})

// Both do not work
```

Comment: I think refactoring your grouped objects to have uniform keys will save you a lot of trouble `const ObjectB = [{date: '25/10/21', count: 4}];` then you can just `const ArrayB = ObjectB.map(o => o.count);`

Comment: Thanks aven't fought about it this way, but i can't do things such as `open[createdDate].count = 0` without getting an typeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way, breaking down each step into a function:

- Add missing dates to each opposite object array (`addMissing()`)
- Sort each object array (`sort()`)
- Get the values of each object array (`getValues`)

```js
const ObjectA = [{ "20/10/21": 3 }, { "25/10/21": 1 }];
const ObjectB = [{ "25/10/21": 4 }];

const addMissing = (oppObj) => {
  return (obj) => {
    let [[date]] = Object.entries(obj);
    if (!oppObj.some((obj) => Object.entries(obj)[0][0] === date)) {
      oppObj.push({ [date]: null });
    }
  };
};

const sort = (a, b) => {
  const splitA = Object.keys(a)[0].split("/");
  const splitB = Object.keys(b)[0].split("/");

  return (
    new Date(splitA[2], splitA[1] - 1, splitA[0]) -
    new Date(splitB[2], splitB[1] - 1, splitB[0])
  );
};

const getValues = (o) => Object.values(o)[0];

// Add missing dates to each opposite object array
ObjectA.forEach(addMissing(ObjectB));
ObjectB.forEach(addMissing(ObjectA));

// Sort each object array
ObjectA.sort(sort);
ObjectB.sort(sort);

// Get the values of each object array
const resA = ObjectA.map(getValues);
const resB = ObjectB.map(getValues);

console.log(resA);
console.log(resB);
```